# Convert coordinates like 23AC to (x,y)

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, casting

I have matrix of coordinates in format XXYY where XX and YY are numbers (0 to 10,000) but Y is represented using letters (A = 1, B = 2, AA = 27 and so on).

points = ["2B", "29AA", "18F", "5AG"]

how can i convert this to something like?

xy_points = [(2, 2), (29, 27), (18, 6), (5, 33)]

My first thought was to use int() and ord(), but things get complicated when a Y coordinate is more than one letter (AZ, AE, BE).

```
A = ["1", "2", "3", "B"]
C = [list(map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else ord(x) - 64, A))]
print(C)
```

I know i can get the string letter by letter and convert it to an integer using base 26. (i.e. for AG would be (ord("A") - 64) * 26 + (ord("G") - 64)). But that would involve a lot of lines.

Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: Actually using base 26 wouldn't work because AA would be 270 and not 27

Comment: So how is Y=0 represented?

Comment: there is no 0, just positive integers starting from 1,1

Comment: If it uses XXYY format, shouldn't it be "02-B"?

Comment: @RohithS98 I mean, the second part of the string is represented with [A-Z] characters, and it could be any quantity of characters from 1 to the amount of characters in 100,000 (which i guess is 4), in base 26 alphabeth (not using numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive function like this will do:

```
def y(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return ord(s[0]) - ord('A') + 1
    return y(s[-1]) + 26 * y(s[:-1])
print(y('B'), y('AA'), y('F'), y('AG'), y('AA'), y('BA'), y('ZZ'), y('AAA'))
```

This outputs:

```
2 27 6 33 27 53 702 703
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Simple and effective. Thank you!